# Asymptotic number of certain transition in a two-state Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value, transition-matrix

Having a two-state Markov chain with the symmetric transition matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
1-p&p\\
p&1-p
\end{pmatrix}
The states are 1 and 2, let $n_{2\rightarrow1}(t)$ be the number of transitions from state 2 to state 1 up to time t (after t total transitions).

I was wondering if the ratio $\frac{n_{2\rightarrow1}(t)}{t}$ converges to a specific value or no.

I tried to calculate the expected value of $n_{2\rightarrow1}(t)$: $\sum_{n=1}^{t}np_{n}$, where $p_n$ is the probability of finding n $2\rightarrow1$ transitions up to t total transitions, but i'm not sure that this is the correct form to find the expectancy, any help would be really appreciated.